# Need a UI tool to compare 2 linux folders from a windows server

Tags: linux, windows, compare, beyondcompare, meld

Need a UI tool to compare 2 linux folders (from 2 different servers) from a  third windows server.

something like beyondCompare or meld that I can visually explore the folders of remote linux servers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond Compare for Windows supports comparison of two Linux servers.

Beyond Compare Standard for Windows can access Linux servers by FTP or as a network drive if the Linux server paths are shared using Samba.

Beyond Compare Pro for Windows adds the ability to access Linux servers by FTPS and SFTP.

Supported comparison types are listed in Beyond Compare's [Feature List](http://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php?zz=features_list).